# Error running RScript in Excel VBA

Tags: r, vba, shell, excel

I've searched through several solutions to this same problem, but my code still doesn't work. Made sure to not have spaces in my file path, and still have it triple quoted to be sure. I get the "Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3' failed" error from running the macro. What could I be missing here?

Code:

```
Sub RunRscript()
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 1
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    Dim path As String
    path = "RScript ""G:\structureshouston\Kocian\hello.R"""
    errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you actually run Rscript from your command line? Is it accessible via your Path environment variable?

Comment: what is `errorCode` after it errors out?

Comment: Is the `.r` file extension associated with `rscript.exe` ? Can you omit the program and run it by association?

Comment: I am able to run the Rscript from cmd, yes. It works perfectly when done that way. I actually just tried it out now and get no error messages. Made no changes over the weekend or anything else. So bizzare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your level of quotes is incorrect.  The RScript should be in quotes while the filename for the script shouldn't be.  Also, I like to make sure I include the full path names in the call.  Try:

```
path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4revised\bin\RScript"" G:\structureshouston\Kocian\hello.R"
```

You may need to update the path to RScript depending on the version you have installed.

Comment: it helped me too. Can you please tell how to send variable to R with the path too

Comment: @aman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698929/passing-variables-from-vba-to-r-script or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139735/how-to-pass-an-argument-from-excel-vba-to-a-script-in-rstudio

Answer (score 0):

it took a little effort to get this going, but the following worked for me.

```
Sub RunRscript1()
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 1
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    Dim path As String

    ' path to R executable:  C:\Users\rshuell001\Documents\R\R-3.2.5\bin\x64\R.exe
    ' path to R script:  C:\Users\rshuell001\Documents\R\Download.r
    ' see more setup details here
    ' http://shashiasrblog.blogspot.com/2013/10/vba-front-end-for-r.html
    path = "C:\Users\rshuell001\Documents\R\R-3.2.5\bin\x64\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave C:\Users\rshuell001\Documents\R\Download.r"
    'path = """C:\Users\rshuell001\Documents\R\R-3.2.5\bin\i386"" C:\Users\rshuell001\Documents\R\Download.R"
    errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

Make sure you read about setting up the 'permissions' using the link below.

http://shashiasrblog.blogspot.com/2013/10/vba-front-end-for-r.html